# Is a disconnected user listed by the who command with a nohup script running in background?

Tags: ssh

Do some of you know about this?

- A user connects to a remote computer with `ssh`
- He then runs a program (in background) like this: `nohup a.out &`
- He disconnects from the computer.

Is he still listed as connected with the `who` command because he has a process running with his name? Or even with `ps aux | grep ssh` ?

I did some research on the internet but could not find a precise answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> Is he still listed as connected with the who command because he has a process running with his name?

No, because that's not what the `who` command lists.

Commands such as `who`, `w`, `finger`, `pinky`, and `users` simply read the **/var/run/utmp** file which is a database of "login sessions" maintained by the login managers themselves. So when you log in via SSH, it's *sshd* which adds an entry to utmp. When your SSH connection ends, sshd removes that entry, *regardless* of what processes might remain.

> Or even with ps aux | grep ssh ?

No, because there's no SSH connection anymore, therefore no reason for the user's sshd instance to linger around anymore.